# Looking for Driver Diagnostic and Repair Software

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, bsod, repair, diagnostic

Greetings,

I am currently plagued with BSODS on startup (both normal and safe mode) for my XP Pro.  After much troubleshooting I have determined it is a driver problem.  However, because I cannot even boot I do not know how to fix it.

I am looking for some specific driver diagnostic and repair software that I can use from another computer to access and fix the driver problem on the problematic XP drive.  (I can access the problematic drive via USB from another computer.)

I will offer more details about my specific situation if it is helpful or necessary.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this all started with an initial bluescreen while the OS was running, there are likely dump files that you could analyze.  You might consider using [WinDbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/Devtools/Debugging/default.mspx) to analyze the dumps to determine the culprit driver.  You could grab the files over USB, as you said, and debug them on another system.

Comment: This is true.  I can definitely due this because there were some initial BSODs.  Plus I can also access Event Viewer remotely using one of the applications in UBCD4Win I believe.  

However, how can I repair/delete the bad driver once I locate it?  Wouldn't deleting just a specific driver file be a bad idea?  Is there some software/tool I can use on a good system (through USB) to remove the driver from the problematic drive?

Answer (score 0):

Older article here but if you look at Nirsoft's [Blue Screen View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) it will help you find the drivers that could be causing the issue. It isn't as good as using WinDbg but for those that don't know what WinDbg is telling them it is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give [DriverMax](http://www.drivermax.com/) a try? Free and paid versions, **it is a driver backup and restore software**...it also offers many rare and up-to-date drivers for numerous manufacturers, etc...works well...